# How do i configure network adapter in guest os of Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, networking

I have my Host with Windows Vista. I am connected to internet through a router. I have both wireless connection to router and LAN connection. I use either of them to connect to network.

I recently have installed windows xp in my guest os. It works fine. After installation i was able to browse internet and update my antivirus software[NOD32] too. But after updating the antivirus now i am unable to connect to network nor to internet.

Previously my network device was setup like NAT and some mac address. Later i tried using NAT, host only and other options too but none worked.

So is it the fault of antivirus or the network adapter configuration error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply desactivate NOD32 & test if you got the connexion back. if so try yo manipulate NOD32 firewall parametre & connexion filtring.

try also to ping from the guest os on the host ip. maybe it's simply a dns or protocol problem.

Comment: uninstalled and again reinstalled worked